# NewRelic not capturing database queries

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, newrelic

NewRelic not capturing database queries. Other queries are ok, that is a signal that the agent is running and everything is ok.

However, I can not see the database queries on the explorer, I just have the PHP agent.

Do I need the database agent running?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the PHP agent docs to validate if your service is running a framework/db connector supported by the agent out of box: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/php-agent/getting-started/php-agent-compatibility-requirements/#databases

If your agent isn't reporting any transactions, then you probably won't see any database/query details. You should validate that you see transactions that are making DB calls and that you don't need any custom instrumentation to capture the DB calls.